# require_once('page1.php') in page 2 shows page 1 in a whole in page 2 like an iframe

Tags: php, require, require-once

I just wanted to use the input from an other page on the current page to show what the user typed in. But instead the whole page, from which the input comes, appears in the page liek an iframe. 
I tried include and i put the require once in the head, but it didn`t work.

This is page 2 (student.php)

```
<html>
<head lang='de'>
    <title>Admin User Verwaltung</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div class="row" id="header">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img src="logo.png" id="logo">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1 id="heading">Benutzeroberfläche User</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p id="profile">
                <?php  
                    require_once ('log_in.php');
                    echo $_POST['user_name'];
                ?>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

and thats page 1 (log_in.php)

```
  <form method="POST" action="log_in.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="">
                <!-- <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Ca3dsumBPuWvCa7tJ13oK6khcG6HVhfY1X9bxQhK"> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>User Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" tabindex="1" required="true" placeholder="z.B. User001" autofocus="true" name="username" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="d-flex">Passwort
                        <a class="ml-auto" href="https://studentenportal.fhws.de/password-reset">Passwort vergessen?</a>
                    </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="password" class="form-control" tabindex="2" required="true" name="password" type="password" placeholder="6 bis 15 zeichen">
                </div>
        </div>

                <!--angemeldet bleiben-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="remember" tabindex="3" value="1" id="remember">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remember">Angemeldet bleiben</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="4">Anmelden</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Hello Kai. You need to show us what is on page1.php and page2.php. Create a small example case with the bare minimum to help us see the issue and add it to the list.

Comment: This makes no sense. You've appear to have somewhat misunderstood how the web works, and how PHP works.`require_once ('log_in.php');` will cause that script to be executed, and show the result. As you've shown us, log_in.php simply contains a HTML form. So the result will be that the form is displayed in your page. If you want to see what the user typed in, then you have to wait for them to complete the form and submit it! When they submit it, that will generate a new request to the server.

Comment: As per the form's `action`, that submitted form data will be sent to `log_in.php` for processing. Only then can some PHP code in `log_in.php` (code which you haven't shown us, assuming it even exists) read the submitted values from `$_POST` and use them.  `student.php` can never read those values because it's not the target URL for the form, and also the form has not even been submitted yet when student.php is being executed. Remember that each the browser sends a request, that creates a new instance of the PHP script being called. Variables are not shared between requests or between scripts

Comment: P.S. your code has nothing to do with iframes. You've simply included some HTML from another script in the first one. The combined output is then sent to the browser as a single document. That's quite a normal thing to do in a PHP application.